# Unable to set my screen resolution higher, solution suggested does not work

Tags: scripts, display, display-resolution

I tried this:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync 
xrandr --addmode VGA-1 "1920x1080_60.00"
```

But this makes my system give the purple screen, after logging in as a user.

Adding <kbd>ENTER</kbd> does not work either, you just get an extra button to click after logging in as a user, and then when you click, you get the purple screen again

The code is not very clear, should you type `'` and <kbd>ENTER</kbd>`'` on the same line, or on a new line? Type it without the word 'and'? It just does not work, you keep getting the purple screen after, and I can't stress that enough, after reboot and userlogin have been completed.

Comment: What is the model of the screen you are trying to apply this to?  Normally xrandr automatically detects maximum screen resolution -- you might be trying to force something the screen doesn't suport.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution, the trick is to not attach your external monitor when starting your laptop, then when you login as the user that the script is made for, you get a pop up, asking you to confirm, after confirming only then attach the external monitor

go to the config for the displays and you will find the higher resolution that you defined in the script is in the list for the display

xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DP-2 "1920x1080_60.00"
<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

The last line of code will probably be printed as ENTER on this page, but it should read < k b d > E N T E R < / k b d >

Just remove the spaces from the last piece of code.

next question will be how to get the creation of code blocks to work in here lol